# Clipping multiple rasters by matching polygons from SPDF in R

Tags: raster, r, parallel

I have about 50.000 small glacier rasters (rectangular shape) that need to be clipped to the glacier's extent. I have the glacier polygons stored in a large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame.

I want to use parallel computing or else it would take forever, I think. For previous tasks I've successfully used the `mcmapply`function, but I am open for other approaches.

My (admittedly rudimentary) code so far is:

```
filenames <- list.files("/.../RGI60-13_reproj/", pattern="*.tif", full.names=F)
filelocations <- list.files("/.../RGI60-13_reproj/", pattern="*.tif", full.names=T)
glaciers <- readOGR("/.../13_rgi60_CentralAsia.shp",verbose=TRUE)

fun_clip <- function(filelocations, filenames, glaciers){
  r <- raster(filelocations)
  r <- crop(r,glaciers) # here I need to clarify the corresponding shp in the SPDF
  writeRaster(r, paste0("/.../RGI60-13_crop/",filenames))
}

mcmapply(fun_proj, filelocations, filenames, mc.cores = 50)
```

How can I give the `crop`-function the right iterative arguments? `filelocation`is of the same length as `glaciers`, so in a `for-loop`I would use something like
`r <- crop(r,glaciers[i])`, but how do I pass the iteration in my kind of function? 
What would be the way to introduce the `i`, so to speak?

Answer (score 1):

"filelocation is of the same length as glaciers" and in the same order? In which case:

```
for(i in 1:length(filelocations)){
  r = raster(filelocations[i]) # get the ith file name
  g = glaciers[i,] # get the i'th row of `glaciers`.
  r = crop(r, g) # crop
  writeRaster(r, file.path(outputdest, filenames[i])) # save in outputdest
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Something like that was my first approach, too, but it was taking forever, so I was hoping for a solution that would allow for computing on different cores (using for example rslurm or parallel)...

Comment: You can modify the above to use `foreach` and `%dopar%` - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: I just found out that we are required to use the ```rslurm``` package for our cluster, so I will open a new question directly about that.